# Radio buttons disappear in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, radio-button

I have this table cell, to which I'm appending a radio button through jQuery. It shows up OK in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE. 
I'm pasting in the minimized versions of this (just the code for a single radio button instead of all of them)

Here's the table row:

```
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align:top">
            <strong>Hard drive type:</strong></td>
        <td id="custom_hddtype">
            </td>
    </tr>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
$('#custom_hddtype').append('<input type="radio" name="hddtype" id="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id']+'" value="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id'] />'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['name']+'<br />');
```

does anybody have any idea why this doesn't show up?

Comment: What are the values of your variables? In other words, what is the generated HTML? Are you sure valid HTML is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the ending quote for the `value` attribute here:

```
value="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id'] />
```

It should be:

```
value="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id']+'" />
                                             ^^ missing
```

When done, it should look like this overall:

```
$('#custom_hddtype').append('<input type="radio" name="hddtype" id="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id']+'" value="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id']+'" />'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['name']+'<br />');
```

Comment: aaaaahhhhrrrr... I hate it when this happens! Thanks a bunch. I wish it wouldn't have worked in the first place or at least Firebug would've indicated something..

Answer (score 1):

try to use this one

```
$('#custom_hddtype').append('<input type="radio" name="hddtype" id="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id']+'" value="'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['id']+'" />'+products_custom['hddtype'][i]['name']+'<br />');
```